# limiting string size in c++ to number of characters

Tags: c++

i have gotten a good exposure in C but am new to C++. I was wondering, is there a way to limit C++ string to number of characters. For eg: if i want to declare a string named "circle", can i limit number of characters to 50? (like we used to do in C, char circle[50])

Comment: If you are using C++ use string data type. Do things in `C`++ish way not in `C`ish way.

Comment: ***if i want to declare a string named "circle"*** In `c++` you do that as `std::string circle;` and let c++ handle the details of resizing the buffer when needed. Eventually your class will teach you `c++`. I assume you are not permitted to use it now however.

Comment: Yes yaman, that is what i want to know, how to allocate size of 50 bytes to a string in C++ish way.

Answer (score 1):

> can i limit number of characters to 50?

You can construct a string with the capacity to hold 50 characters by using:

```
std::string str(50, '\0');
```

However, unlike C arrays, it is possible to increase its size by adding more data to it.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string str(50, '\0');
   for (size_t i = 0; i < 49; ++i )
   {
      str[i] = 'A'+i;
   }

   std::cout << str << std::endl;

   str += " Some more characters.";

   std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopq
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopq Some more characters.
```

Comment: Thanks @R_Sahu, this helps a lot!